# How to sort data in asp.net according to varchar datetime field in SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime

I have a table with a column `DateTime` with datatype `VARCHAR(500)`.

I'm storing date and time info in it. I'm getting the datetime value using C#

```
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "," + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
```

This gives me the format like this: 14 July 2015,12:56:04.

I want to sort data in gridview by this column, but since it is of `VARCHAR` this gives incorrect result. I have understood that there is something about conversion, but haven't been able to do that.

Any suggestion regarding dis will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to do the sorting on the sql server side or c# side?

Comment: i want to do sorting on c# asp.net side.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If it's a date - **store it as such!** - don't store a date&time as `Varchar` - that's exactly the kind of problems you're getting yourself into if you do! If it's a date&time - **use** `DATETIME` (or `DATETIME2(n)` on SQL Server 2008 and newer)

Comment: I hope it will work if you remove "," in between date and time. And convert this string to DateTime at the time of sorting

Comment: no its nt working.. @gkrishy

Comment: Instead of "," , you gave a space in between ?. If not, give an attempt in that way

Comment: i hv tried dis...bt i m nt getting correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boundfield for the datetime column in the Gridview then this will help you in the design of your Gridview:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="DateColumn" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Comment: its not working...I'm getting the same result as before.